# cocos2d Using camera to take picture and save that to file

Tags: ios, image, cocos2d-iphone, camera

cocos2d Using camera to take picture and save that to file

I can use camera to take picture.
But this picture is a part of this picture.(a white White border)

How get a big picture?

I want to get a clear picture.

thank you！！

```
-(void)takePhoto{
AppController *appdel = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
@try {

uip = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] ;
uip.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
uip.allowsEditing = YES;
uip.delegate = self;
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
[uip release];
uip = nil;
}
@finally {
if(uip) {
[appdel.navController presentModalViewController:uip animated:YES];
}
}
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
profileImage=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerCropRect];
AppController *appdel = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appdel.navController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[uip release];
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(writeImgToPath:) toTarget:self withObject:profileImage];
}

-(void)writeImgToPath:(id)sender
{

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
UIImage *image = sender;
NSArray *pathArr = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
NSUserDomainMask,
YES);
CGSize size;
int currentProfileIndex = 1;
NSString *path = [[pathArr objectAtIndex:0]
stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Img_%d.png",currentProfileIndex]];

size = CGSizeMake(1320, 480);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1320, 480)];
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
NSLog(@”Saved…..”);

CGRect r = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1320, 480);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(r.size);

UIImage *img1;

[image drawInRect:r];
img1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img1, nil, nil, nil);
[pool release];

}
-(id) init
{

[self takePhoto];

}
return self;
}
```